# Change column of row action (Quick Edit) links in WP_List_Table

Tags: custom-post-types, admin, dashboard, columns, wp-list-table

Is it possible to move the "Edit | Quick Edit | Trash", etc... links (A/K/A "Quick Edit links") from a table generated by a custom post type registration into a different column other than the "Title" column?

Perhaps a custom column?

Is there a action/filter for this? Or can I just remove the "Title" column, and add a column called "Actions", and just stick the links there with a function call of some sort?

[image]

Comment: You mean [the quick edit](https://www.google.at/search?q=wordpress+quick+edit+filter&oq=wordpress+quick+edit+filter&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i60j69i64l2.3276j0j7&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8) and [the bulk edit box](https://www.google.at/search?q=wordpress+bulk+edit&oq=wordpress+bulk+edit&aqs=chrome..69i57j69i61j0l4.3286j0j4&sourceid=chrome&espv=210&es_sm=93&ie=UTF-8#es_sm=93&espv=210&q=wordpress+bulk+edit+filter)? What have you tried so far? And yes, I know, it's no easy stuff...

Comment: @kaiser I'm talking about those three links right under the post title in my super tiny screen shot. I just want to append those links to a different column, so I can just get rid of the "Title" column for this particular custom post type's post listing table.

Comment: Still, that's called "Quick Edit" in WP. Please [edit] your question and search for that specifically.

Comment: you can check this answer [Move custom column admin links from bellow “post title”][1]it may help you :)


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13418722/move-custom-column-admin-links-from-bellow-post-title